# Do I have to submit my original EU residency permit when applying for a UK visa from a Schengen consulate?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, italy, standard-visitor-visas

I know this question has been asked a million times with a million variations. But I never read anything regarding my query.

I am applying for a UK visit visa from Italy. I am an Indian national, so it's a bit tricky to navigate the whole process. I have already translated my work contract, pay slips and bank statements, which I will submit.

As I will submit my original passport, do I have to submit my original permesso (residence permit) as well or would a copy of it do? Because without the passport and permesso, I basically have no valid ID with me left.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: I’d imagine that you can submit certified photocopies of your Permesso, others with more knowledge may confirm or advise otherwise

Comment: No, it's not among with the required documents; including a copy as evidence of your residence is fine, but attach a translation (that is mentioned for any document not in English or Welsh).

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not have to submit your *permesso di soggiorno* card, along with your passport, while applying for the UK Standard Visit visa. it's not among with the required documents, but you will need to provide the details in response to [this query](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589170/VAF1-visitandshorttermstay.pdf):

> 8.1 If you are not a national of the country in which you are applying, what permission do you have to stay in that country?

You can add a photocopy as evidence. As @MichaelHampton points out, *a translation is probably not necessary, as the residence permit has the same standard format across EU countries.*

Comment: A translation is _probably_ not necessary, as the residence permit has the same standard format across EU countries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton true and, when I look at one, nothing should need translation; ty; I'll amend the response.